# Input check after scanf goes wrong

Tags: c

Here's a part of a function that supposed to scan an integer between 0 and 100.
The program goes wrong when the user inputs a char. anyone has an idea? iv'e tried a Combined condition like this one: `if(scanf("%d",&test)&&(test<=100&&test>=0))`
it didn't work...

```
while(i!=4)
{
    printf("\nPlease enter your homework grade: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&hw))
    {
        ++i;
    }
    if(hw<=100&&hw>=0)
    {
        ++i;
    }
    printf("\nPlease enter your test grade: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&test))
    {
        ++i;
    }
    if(test<=100&&test>=0)
    {
        ++i;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease re-enter the required details\n");
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, `scanf` is notoriously hard to use properly and usually should be avoided. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a character is read using `%d` then the ASCII value of it is stored in the memory. 
If you want a `Integer Proofing` mechanism, then use the below code. Get the user input as a string, check if any character is present, if present then return error, else convert that string to integer and use the same for further processing.

```
char n[4];  /* To store max of 3 char's `100` including '\0' */
int i=0, flag=1;
scanf("%3s",  n);

while(n[i] != '\0'){
    flag = isdigit(n[i]);

    if (!flag)
        break;
    i++;
}

if(flag) 
{ 
   i=atoi(n);
   printf("%d", i);
}
else
{
   printf("it's not integer");
}
```

Comment: That code is very prone to buffer overflow, you should `scanf("%3s", n)` (and probably make the buffer larger, too). As an alternative to hand-coded proofing, the function `strtol` from `<stdlib.h>` does both proofing and conversion for you.

Comment: @MOehm: Thanks, updated my answer. At max only three characters are to be read. so I don't think it is necessary to increase buffer size.

Comment: Well, maybe for error diagnosis. When the user types "10000", you'll want a "number too big" instead of silently treating that as "100".

Answer (score 0):

you have to make while(i!=2){....}

Try the program in this way....

main()
{

```
int i, hw, test;

while(i!=2)
{
    i=0;
    printf("\nEnter the hmwrk grade: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&hw)&&(hw<=100&&hw>=0))
        ++i;

    printf("\nEnter the test grade: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&test)&&(test<=100&&test>=0))
        ++i;

    if(i!=2)
        printf("\nPlease reenter the req details..\n");
}
```

}